# Windows Powershell ISE Just Run First Line of Function Invoke Command ScriptBlock

Tags: powershell

This is my code snippet :

```
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName dafwkn409c6c9 -Credential $mycreds


function Foo (){
    Get-ChildItem C:\
    Get-ChildItem d:\ 
}

function Foo1 (){
    Get-ChildItem d:\ 
}

Invoke-Command  -Session $s -ScriptBlock ${function:Foo}
Invoke-Command  -Session $s -ScriptBlock ${function:Foo1}
```

Function Foo has 2 Line. Foo1 has 1 line.

But when I give my code to my friend, or I run my code at the server, the function Foo run all of lines.

This just happened my computer, my foo function just run first line.

Please suggest where to fix my powershell ISE.

[image: samplecode]

[image: version]

Why my last code at function foo not called?
[image: secondline]

My DotNet 4.5 says no, 
[image: dotnet]

but when I install dotnet 4.5 this dialog says something

[image: dotnet45]

Comment: which ps version you are in ?

Comment: Not sure if that way can work, but try it this way: `Invoke-Command  -Session $s -ScriptBlock (Get-Command Foo).ScriptBlock`

Comment: @RanadipDutta Please check updated post. Is that right way to check my PS version?  
For MatthewWetmore :  I guess this code is fine. So I do not want to update my script. I am just need update my PS version or change the setting so the PS behaviour / environtment is like another computer or my server environtment. Btw thank you for your kind help

Comment: There is no issue on that.You are calling properly only. Remove the second function ,foo1, from the script and the second invoke from the script. It is able to pick both c drive and d drive items without any issue.

Comment: @toha: Yes you are in version 5. and your script is absolutely fine. If you wish to have screenshot I can give it to you. I have test it in 3 diff systems and resulting properly. Even you can invoke the commands like Matthew told. That way it will run get-childitem c and get-childitem d in the same order as you have mentioned in the scriptblock.

Comment: Any suggestion Mr. @RanadipDutta ? How to set my PS like another computer? Is there setting to this case? My friend usually use gyazo to share screenshot.. It will upload directly to web..

Comment: I have updated my post. Please check. My drive D is not listed. This is always like that. My first line at functions called, but not with second line and so on.

Comment: http://mikefrobbins.com/2015/01/08/how-to-check-the-powershell-version-and-install-a-new-version/
My dot net 4.5 says no Sir. Mikefrobbins says it make PS one liner.

Comment: Could u pls try running the entire thing in PowerShell.exe instead of ise and see the outcome once..it shoud give u properly there.

Comment: It is same Sir. I think I must doing domething with my ps 5. It need .net 4.5 but I think my PS does not detect my .net 4.5 well.

Comment: https://powershell.org/2014/05/21/installing-powershell-v5-be-a-little-careful-ok/
Now I am trying to uninstall PS 5. I want to downgrade to version 4.

Comment: @RanadipDutta Can You please tell me how to uninstall My PS 5? and back to version 2?

Comment: wusa /uninstall /kb:3134760
 says no update installed

Comment: Can u tell me the reason?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/EwkAe

I have installed PS Version 4. But when I check my PS Version it is always 5. How to change it to 4 or another version?

Comment: Finally, I re install PS version 5.0. Then after re-install I can Update to 5.1. I hope the case is because 5.0 bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I update My PS Version, to version 5.1

It is because [5.0 bug's](https://powershell.org/2014/05/21/installing-powershell-v5-be-a-little-careful-ok/) I guess. That article says :

- v5 is a preview. It isn't done, and it isn't guaranteed bug-free. It
  shouldn't be installed on production computers until it's officially
  released.
- v5 doesn't install 'side by side' with v3 or v4. You can't
  run it with "-version 3" to "downgrade." Now, v5 shouldn't break
  anything - something that runs in v3 or v4 should still work fine -
  but there are no guarantees as it's a preview and not released code
  at this stage.
- Server software (Exchange, SharePoint, etc) often has
  a hard dependency on a specific version of PowerShell. You need to
  look into that before you install v5.
- After installing v5, you might
  not be able to cleanly uninstall and revert to a prior version.

The point is :

> Generally speaking, v5 should be installed in a test virtual machine
>   at the very least, **not on a production computer**. It's great to play
>   with it, and you should absolutely log bugs and suggestions to
>   http://connect.microsoft.com.

When I run this block of codes:

```
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName dafwkn409c6c9 -Credential $mycreds

function Foo (){
    Get-ChildItem C:\
    Get-ChildItem d:\ 
}

Invoke-Command  -Session $s -ScriptBlock ${function:Foo}
```

All of codes at function executed well.

Please **beware** with Powershell 5.0

Comment: Thank you Master Ranadip. You are awesome.